# Help understanding a written statistics statement

Tags: mixed-model, variance, model

can someone help me understand what my professor meant when he typed out `beta^2*var(x)/(\sum_j beta_j^2*var(x_j)+sigma_u^2)` as a way to compute the proportion of variance explained by `x` where `beta` is the coefficient estimate? My difficulty in understanding this statement comes from x being a vector of single terms so I could get variance of x (`var(x)`), but I don't see what `var(x_j)` could be. Does `var(x)` maybe have an alternate meaning?

Any help would be great; I just want to make sure this is actually difficult to understand before bothering him with another message.

Comment: Is this a single variable regression, or multivariate regression?

Comment: Please use math formatting. More information here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user777 that is the precise issue. I was given that statement in this format and cannot figure out how to parse it

Comment: @MatthewDrury Would that matter? There is at least one predictor variable (x) and an intercept term along with other potential covariates

Comment: Because if there is more than one predictor the `x` is pretty ambiguous, and the presence of an `x_j` makes it seem like that is indeed the case.

Comment: Alright, that makes a ton of sense. I was thinking of j as individuals (which seemed absurd) but if j is each predictor (even if it's only x and the intercept) that would make more sense. Then the numerator would just be the `x` term I'm individually interested in.